# How to use await in schedule library?

Tags: async-await, telegram, telegram-bot, schedule

I got this exception7 How to fix it?

RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'job' was never awaited
self._run_job(job)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

```
from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot, executor
from aiogram.types import Message,CallbackQuery
from asyncio import sleep
import schedule

bot = Bot(token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message : Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)


async def job():
    await bot.send_message(626420006, 'job done!')
    

async def scheduler():
    schedule.every(2).seconds.do(lambda : job())

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        await sleep(1)
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dp.loop.create_task(scheduler())
    executor.start_polling(dp,skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used another library aioschedule

```
from aiogram import Dispatcher, Bot, executor
from aiogram.types import Message,CallbackQuery
import asyncio
import time
import aioschedule as schedule

bot = Bot('')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message : Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)


async def job():
    print('hello')
    await bot.send_message(626420006, 'job done!')
    

async def scheduler():
    
    schedule.every(1).seconds.do(job)

    # loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        await schedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dp.loop.create_task(scheduler())
    executor.start_polling(dp,skip_updates=True)
```